# How to set up table for HAND based flood extents in ArcHydro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arc-hydro, flood

I have a stream line and points with surface water elevation and a DEM of the watershed. I really liked the look of the HAND-based on Flood Depth and Extent but I would like to use the water elevation/depth values at each point I have rather than a set depth for the entire watershed. To accomplish this I think I need to use the hand-based flood depth and extent from table tool however I can't see to figure out how to set everything up and I keep getting an error that I am missing a valid statistic. I think my issue is in the attributes and values of the input flood depth table. What attributes are required and what would be expected values for the attributes?

I am currently running ArcGIS Pro 3.1 with the Arc-hydro tools